# Troubleshooting Sako Solar Inverter and Osaka Battery Charging Issue

Tags: power-electronics, battery-charging, inverter, solar-energy, troubleshooting

I have a solar power system comprising a Sako inverter (3.5-5.5 kW) and two Osaka P-180 S batteries with 21 plates per cell. Despite receiving input from the solar panels, the inverter does not produce any output, and the batteries remain uncharged. Here are the observations I've made:

The solar panel input reads 145 V, 0 A, and 8 W.
Despite these readings, there is no current output from the inverter, and the batteries do not charge.
I've checked all connections, verified the functionality of each component, and reviewed the system settings, but I'm unable to identify the cause of the issue. What could be causing this lack of output from the inverter and failure to charge the batteries? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem?

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solar panels are not generating any current (well, 55 mA), if the measurements are correct, so nothing happens downstream from them. Good place to start troubleshooting.

Comment: The solar panels are wired correctly, clean, and receive full sunlight with no shading. They work for a day or two, but on other days, they do not seem to work or pass current. What could be the issue?